# Entity Framework 7 - Central Table that joins to most tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Let's say  you have a table:

Document
-- DocumentId int PK
-- DocumentName  varchar
-- EntityTypeId  int
-- EntityId   int

Also you have other business entities like House, Car, Boat, Motorcycle, etc that are entitytype with their own ids.  Each one of them may have 0 or X documents.

How could you build this relationship in EF7, not sure it is possible, and/or how would you join this data in a query in EF.

Comment: this is not possible in EF because it's not possible in SQL server.

Comment: In sql you can write a join query to the table.  I know I can't add foreign keys to it.  Just looking for any thoughts to doing it all manual vs some other way.

Comment: the only way is to do it all manual because EF needs the referential constraints to create a navigation property

Comment: This is called *polymorphic associations*. You'll find many hits.

Comment: Thanks almost nothing with regard to ef core but I'll read up to see if there is anything useful.